# Placing a Pug extends anywhere in a file?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm currently following this Jade tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l5AXcXAP4r8 (I know Jade is Pug now but I'm watching jade tutorials to get familiar with it since many don't exist for pug) and at 24:25 the instructor places an 'extends filename' in the middle of his index.jade file. This works fine for him but this does not work for me when executing with pug. I get an error in my terminal saying "Declaration of template inheritance ("extends") should be the first thing in the file." Is it not possible in pug to put an extends in the middle of a file and it used to be possible with jade? Is there any way to make it possible? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Could you paste/ show how your version of the code looks like?

Comment: @staar sorry I'm not sure how to make the code readable. This is my first stack overflow post

Comment: @staaar Mine wasn't working so I copied and pasted his code exactly has he gives it and it still was giving me the error. He gives the code here http://www.newthinktank.com/2016/01/learn-jade-one-video/ if you scroll down you can see everything he did. I copied and pasted each part after not being able to have it work with my following along but even copying and pasting exactly what he did didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with pug. The error message is fairly clear, `extends`must be the first thing in the file, it cannot be placed in the middle. Without any code (or idea of what you're trying to achieve), it is difficult to tell if you could find a workaround for this (using mixins perhaps?).